# Application throw exception in configuration Debug but work in Release

Tags: c#, serial-port, release

I am trying to repair applications after my no longer working colleague. This application connects with devices by serial port and shows received data in windows form.

It turns out application works almost perfect when I use Release configuration, and throws an exception when it's in Debug.

I used other program to check frame which I send and received. Because in debug exceptions are related with reading this frame. It often throws an exception because frame is too short to read something. I read something that should not get at all, in addition, the second program shows that, despite everything, virtually all frames come correctly.

I don't know possibilities Release and Dubug, and I don't know where I can find something in my project about differences in creating app. Except Configuration Manager which are the same for both.

Can someone tell me why it works in Release and does not in Debug?

App was written in .NET 2.0. Now I changed it to 4.7.2 but it changed nothing in release nor debug.

Comment: Search in entire solution for `#if DEBUG` or `#if RELEASE`. There should show you some possible differences between two modes.

Comment: thanks for response. Unfortunately I didnt find it in my code ;/

Answer (score 1):

did you already tried you rebuild your app or try to delete the debug file and restart your program.

Also this is a good explanation I found

> When you compile in debug mode, you get ".pdb" files along with your .exe or .dll by default. The pdb files are called "symbols". This is what allows exceptions to give you a stack trace that tells you exactly which class and method failed, and even points to the line number in your .cs file. It also allows a debugger to be attached to your running program and allows you to "step through" your code.
>
> When you compile in release mode, the compiler "optimizes" your compiled code (such that execution is as efficient as possible). To do this, it will compile your code a bit differently from what you actually wrote. In so doing, classes, methods and line numbers will not be as accurate if an exception is thrown. In some cases, the exception won't be traceable at except at a binary level, because something has been compiled into classes or methods that are not contained in any .cs file.

Comment: thanks for resposne. I think it can be it, because i didnt find different in code.

Comment: At last application work to slow in debug, and often have problem with read frame.